# Reference request: basics of high-order partial differential operators.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Is there a basic book (accessible to beginning graduate students in real analysis -- not quite PDE theory) on high-order PDE? In particular, I'd like to know what type of boundary conditions (and why) people like to use for high-order elliptic problems. And perhaps a little about the associated Green's functions. I've managed to dig up [Polyharmonic Boundary Value Problems](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-12245-3), but it's a little too advanced for me, jumping right into heavy analysis -- I'm seeking a more basic book/lecture notes if they exist!

Many thanks